# "На ... и наоборот на ..." - нужно ли обособлять наоборот запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

"Переход учреждений на финансовую самостоятельность и наоборот на бухгалтерское обслуживание уже имел место"

Сначала я выделила слово "наоборот" запятыми, но потом засомневалась. Как все-таки правильно?

Comment: *"Наоборот"* - вводное слово, оно должно выделяться запятыми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово наоборот не всегда вводное. Здесь надо смысл предложения понимать, а это может знать только автор. Если  "наоборот" значит "обратно" , то это наречие, не вводное слово. знаками не выделяется.

Здесь по смыслу возможно: учреждения перешли на финансовую самостоятельность (т.е. имеется в виду, сами все считают, без бухгалтера), а потом вернулись обратно на бухгалтерское обслуживание. Тогда знаки должны быть расставлены так:

*"Переход учреждений на финансовую самостоятельность и наоборот, на бухгалтерское обслуживание, уже имел место"* Наоборот (куда именно?),на финансовую самостоятельность (уточняющий член предложения).

Но я не уверена, что смысл поняла верно. А если я все-таки права,то, может, лучше так и написать - обратно...

Comment: Да, смысл такой. В этом и была загвоздка. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы выделила слово НОБОРОТ запятыми как вводное, указывающее на связь мыслей, последовательность изложения: "Переход учреждений на финансовую самостоятельность и, наоборот, на бухгалтерское обслуживание уже имел место".

Answer (score 0):

Запятая после союза **ставится, если** союз не включается во вводную конструкцию, соединяя члены предложения или части сложного предложения (вводное слово можно опустить без нарушения структуры предложения): Ей надо передать ночью важное и, должно быть, невеселое письмо (Ч.)
Запятая после союза **не ставится, если** союз включается во вводную конструкцию, образуя с ней единое сочетание (изъятие вводного слова невозможно): В темном тумане начали появляться обрывочные и бессвязные видения, настолько бессвязные и далекие одно от другого, точно они слетались ко мне от разных людей, а может быть, и не только от людей (Расп.)*(ПАС Лопатина)*
В Вашем предложении вводное слово НАОБОРОТ надо обособить, т.к.  вводное слово можно опустить, а  союз И соединяет однородные члены (на...самостоятельность и на..обслуживание)и не включается во вводную конструкцию. 
***Переход учреждений на финансовую самостоятельность и, наоборот, на бухгалтерское обслуживание уже имел место.***

Comment: Я тоже неправильно поняла предложение. Конечно, вместо слова НАОБОРОТ здесь лучше было бы употребить ОБРАТНО или СНОВА. Согласна с Ларf. Прошу прощения.